# How to show only one pair of linked Highcharts series at a time

Tags: highcharts, toggle

I have a Highcharts column chart with multiple 'pairs', set in an array - where one of the pair is the actual figure and the other is an industry average.

```
var links = {
    'Apples': 'Apples average',
    'Pears': 'Pears average',
    'Oranges': 'Oranges average',
    'Bananas': 'Bananas average'
};
```

.......

```
    series: [{
        id: 'Apples',
        name: 'Apples',
        color: 'rgba(0,167,184,1)',
        data: [3.8, 8.9, 8.4],
        pointPadding: 0.3,
        pointPlacement: 0.2

    }, {
        id: 'Apples average',
        name: 'Apples average',
        color: 'rgba(135,28,90,1)',
        data: [2.7, 8.1, 7.9],
        pointPadding: 0.3,
        pointPlacement: -0.2

    },
```

I'm trying to show **only one pair at a time**, so when the chart is loaded the first pair is visible, and when the next legend item (pair) is clicked, the first pair is hidden, and only the new pair is shown, etc etc.

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0,
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function (event) {
                    var sisterSeries = this.chart.get(links[this.name]);
                    if (this.visible) {
                        sisterSeries.hide();
                    } else {
                        sisterSeries.show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

I can not achieve the on/off toggle effect I need to show just one pair at a time – I still need to manually click the existing pair to hide them. Any help would be appreciated.

There are very similar questions about how to toggle series (http://jsfiddle.net/tK38J/65/) but I can not find one where the data to be toggled is in a pair.

(In the legend of my example I would hide the '... average' menu items so they do not need to actually work as links).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6cL56x9r/4/

Comment: The `linkedTo` property will link the two series together, and only show the first one in the legend. Combine that with the other functionality you've found an answer for, and you should be all set. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.linkedTo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link paired series as was mentioned in the comment. If only a main series should be visible then you can loop inside the legendItemClick event like this:

```
legendItemClick: function (event) {
                    this.chart.series.forEach(function (serie) {
                        if (serie.linkedSeries.length && this != serie) {
                        serie.setVisible(false, false);
                      }
                    }, this);
                }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6cL56x9r/11/

You can keep linked series visible, if you set property showInLegend to true, but then you need to modify the condition in the loop a little.